# How do I make a video cut-scene with XNA 4.0?

Tags: c#, video, import, xna-4.0

I have transitions in my game and they work fine, but I want to now play a video cut-scene between certain transitions but can't find out how to do it.

*EDIT* Actually I just found out that XNA 4.0 has video playing capabilities now, they just have to be in .wmv format. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What do you mean by transitions? Level transitions? And when you say video cut-scene, do you mean play some sort of encoded video file like a WMV or an MPEG? If so, what format do you plan on using?

Comment: @Mike O'Connor Yes to play a avi file during a level transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out http://xnadsplayer.codeplex.com, saw that linked in a few different places.